# Is it possible to style a part of a label?

Tags: geoserver, sld

My label consists of two different things:

```
<ogc:PropertyName>user</ogc:PropertyName>
<ogc:PropertyName>room</ogc:PropertyName>
```

I would like to style the two parts differently, for example have the room number in bold. Is it possible?

Comment: I see that I can use several TextSymbolizers for one node. But then I have a problem with the overlapping between the labels.