# Multi-line and Multi-labels formatting in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, line, text

I am trying to apply different text formatting (bold and italics) to multi-line labels in QGIS. I tried HTML tags as seen below, it show what I wanted in the preview below but it deosn't work on the map.

[image]

Using text styling will apply the style to both line, I just want the first line to have the style.

Any way around this?

Comment: Unfortunately, the HTML solution on labels doesn't work on QGIS for now. It will be possible from the next QGIS version (3.14). Here a good alternative solution to your issue https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/357234/is-there-any-way-to-style-a-substring-of-a-label-with-a-different-style-without/357244#comment584543_357244

Comment: Have you considered using separate labels for the first and second line? (I guess that would require one copy of the layer for each label)